# Impossible to DROP TABLE / postgres / docker

Tags: postgresql, flask, alembic

I'm currently working on a Flask server, and a postgresql database running in a docker. I wanted to delete a table with a migration using alembic, but when I wanted to apply it it was just frozen and I had a process

```
DROP TABLE waiting
```

that was just... waiting...
So I tried to delete the table directly with psql:

```
<db_name>=# DROP TABLE <table_name>
```

But I had the same result, it was never ending, even after supressing all columns in the table.
Btw that table is a list of mails linked to another with users, but it shouldn't be a problem.

Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: when you try to drop it and see waiting - check hat its waiting for. whats postgres version?..

Comment: It's postgres 10.1

Comment: I have:

postgres: <username> <dbname> 172.20.0.1(44192) DROP TABLE waiting

I don't know how to see what it is waiting...

Answer (score 1):

Okay I ran :

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d db
```

And now it work, there was still a connection with a docker of the app, and I worked with my app in local. I totally forgotten the existence of this docker app.

Thanks all, solved !